# Why does Android restrict Drawable filenames to not use Capital letters in their names?

Tags: android, android-drawable

The title above is clear enough.
What exactly could be the reason? Are the capital letters reserved for some specific usage?

Comment: because it doesn't want capitals in filenames

Comment: @Apurva Exactly my point! Why it doesn't?

Comment: To all the downvoters, if my query is worth downvoting, it is also worth answering. So atleast give me an answer!

Comment: Usefull and R&D question.

Answer (score 2):

Each file inside folder is translated into java field name inside `R.java` class.

```
drawable\myicon.png -> R.drawable.myicon
```

Hence the reason for not using special characters inside file names, as they can no be used in Java names.

Refer [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/0g3SUA3yoCk)

Comment: Are capital letters also considered 'special characters'?
P.S. I'm new to Java.

Comment: Okay, I went through some links. When you say "they cannot be used in Java names", what exactly do you mean? I'm asking this coz AFAIK Java names (example class names) do use capital letters.

Comment: no it is not. It could be a limitation of the filesystem where your drawable will be placed. What if the filesystem can't distinguish between Myicon.png myIcon.png and myicon.png?

Comment: For the sake of readability, the framework could have accepted names with capital letters, but could have treated them as same files. Thus avoiding the issue pointed out by @Blackbelt

Comment: *For the sake of readability*, it is not a framework limitation, but it **could** be a limitation of the filesystem.

Comment: @Blackbelt What I'm trying to say is that the android framework could have accepted files with capital letters, but at the backend could have used them as, say, all small letters. This way, nobody gets to complain - neither the user nor the filesystem.